# Menu de opciones en python

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en Python donde debo realizar un menú de opciones
usando funciones, dicho ejercicio se compone de la función menú, función carga donde ingreso datos de empleados, función modificar donde tengo la opción de modificar el sueldo del empleado.

El inconveniente surge cuando ejecuto el código.
donde al  momento de ingresar la opción 2 (función de modificar) salta error, es lo único
por ahí seguramente puede ser algo simple o algo que seguramente he pasado por alto.
pero agradecería que me ayuden a resolverlo de paso para dejar mas en claro algunos conceptos.

```
def menu():
    print("presione 1 para cargar datos de empleados")
    print("presione 2 si desea editar datos")
    opcion=int(input("ingrese una opcion"))
    if opcion==1:
        carga()
    elif opcion==2:
        modicar(datos)
        
def carga():
    datos={}
    continua="s"
    while continua=="s":
        legajos=int(input("ingrese numero de legajo"))
        
        nombre=input("ingrese nombre del empleado")
        profesion=input("ingrese puesto /area/profesion")
        sueldo=int(input("ingrese sueldo del empleado"))
        datos[legajos]=[nombre,profesion,sueldo]
        continua=input("desea agregar otro empleado?")
        if continua!="s":
            menu()      
    return(datos)
   


def modicar(datos):
    legajo=int(input("ingrese numero de legajo a seleccionar"))
    if legajo in datos:
        sueldo=int(input("ingrese el nuevo sueldo"))
        datos[2]=sueldo



 menu()
 datos=carga()
 modicar(datos)
```

Comment: Me parece que estas declarando un diccionario en la funcion carga() y despues lo queres manipular como tupla.

Comment: datos={}  en ves de esto, pone datos=[]

Comment: Tambien, tenes que declararla como una variable global, no local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno en primer lugar voy a comentar que las ultimas dos líneas son innecesarias ya que esas funciones no necesitan ser iniciadas, esto porque ya son llamadas desde la función menu... Con llamar a la funcion menu basta...

Y contestando a tu pregunta la solución es simple, estas llamando a la función modificar con una variable que aun no esta definida, en el mismo error que tira te debe decir algo como "name datos is not defined" o algo así creo, lo que puedes hacer y creo que es una solución que te servirá para muchos otros trabajos es definir una variable global antes de todas las funciones y llamarla luego de definir cada función...

Comment: Deberias acompañar codigo con tu respuesta. sino queda muy pobre

Answer (score 3):

Antes de nada bienvenido a stackoverflow!

He ejecutado tu código y veo un par de errores

### Error de indentación:

A diferencia de otros lenguajes en los que la indentación simplemente ayuda a mejorar la legibilidad del código, en Python la indentación reemplaza lo que en otros lenguajes correspondería a `<begin> <end>` o `{}`, lo que delimita cada bucle, estructura de control, clase o función. Es por esto que se ha de respetar la indentación de forma estricta.

En tu código, al final, donde "comienza el programa"

```
...
X..
 menu()
 datos=carga()
 modicar(datos)
X..
...
```

hay un espaciado justo antes de cada  linea.

### Error variable no definida en edición

Cuando finalizas de agregar usuarios en la función `carga()`, llamas al menú

```
def carga():
  ..
  while continua=="s":
    ..
    if continua!="s":
        menu()
```

sin embargo no retornas los datos almacenados.

En este punto existen formas distintas de implementarlo, dependiendo de lo que busques.

### SOLUCIÓN 1

Podrías simplemente pasarle al menú los datos y aceptarlo como parámetro en el menú, quedando algo así:

```
def carga():
  ..
  while continua=="s":
    ..
    if continua!="s":
        menu(datos)

def menu(datos = {}):
  ..
  if opcion==1:
      carga()
  elif opcion==2:
      modicar(datos)
```

Cuando el usuario no quiera agregar mas empleados, entonces saldrá y seguirá el menú con los datos.

Ahora bien, esto implicaría eliminar la linea `modicar(datos)`, ya que tu programa no se detiene del flujo inicial desde la primera vez que has ejecutado `datos=carga()`.

Por como está definido el programa, cuando llamas a `datos = carga()`, se entiende que SOLO CARGAS los datos, lo que no implica modificación, pues sería otra acción distinta. Por esta razón, no vería "limpia y correcta" esta implementación.

### SOLUCIÓN 2

Acorde a tu programa, creo que lo correcto sería retornar los datos en caso de que el usuario deje de añadir empleados, quedando así:

```
def carga():
  ..
  while continua=="s":
    ..
    if continua!="s":
      break
    return datos
```

Aunque en realidad por el propio while no sería necesario realizar el break (lo agrego solo para que se entienda en la explicación)

De esta forma, termina la "segunda linea del programa `datos = carga()`", quedan retornados y almacenados los datos "al primer nivel de ejecución", y desde ahí, se llama a la "tercera linea de tu programa `modicar(datos)`" correctamente.

Ten en cuenta que por un lado tienes el bucle de opciones del menú y por otro el de agregar empleados.

### POSIBLE CORRECCIÓN COMPLETA

```
def menu():
    datos = {}
    print("presione 1 para cargar datos de empleados")
    print("presione 2 si desea editar datos")
    opcion=int(input("ingrese una opcion"))
    if opcion==1:
        datos = carga()
    elif opcion==2:
        modicar(datos)
    
def carga():
    datos={}
    continua="s"
    while continua=="s":
        legajos=int(input("ingrese numero de legajo"))
        
        nombre=input("ingrese nombre del empleado")
        profesion=input("ingrese puesto /area/profesion")
        sueldo=int(input("ingrese sueldo del empleado"))
        datos[legajos]=[nombre,profesion,sueldo]
        continua=input("desea agregar otro empleado?")

    return(datos)


def modicar(datos):
    legajo=int(input("ingrese numero de legajo a seleccionar"))
    if legajo in datos:
        sueldo=int(input("ingrese el nuevo sueldo"))
        datos[2]=sueldo

# EMPIEZA EL PROGRAMA
continuaMenu = "s"
while continuaMenu=="s":
    menu()
    continuaMenu=input("¿Desea realizar una nueva operación del menú?")
    if continuaMenu != "s":
        print("bye bye")
```

Espero que te ayude ;)

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte y sobre todo por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme con detalles.